# Loop over list of functions, and return function name as character

Tags: r

In R, I have a list of functions (strategies for a simulation). For example:

```
a <- function(x){
        return(x)
      }

b <- function(y){
        return(y)
      }
funclist <- list(a,b)
```

I'd like to write some code that returns the name of each function. Normally, for functions I would use:

```
as.character(substitute(a))
```

But this does not work for the list, as it just would return the list name (as expected). I then tried lapply:

```
> lapply(X = funclist,FUN = substitute)
Error in lapply(X = funclist, FUN = substitute) : 
  '...' used in an incorrect context
```

But get the above error.

Ideally I would get (lapply solution):

```
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"
```

or even (sapply solution):

```
[1] "a" "b"
```

Comment: As stated the problem can only be solved by comparing the list elements to all function defined in the global environment. Be aware that multiple matches are possible. You should change the approach that creates this need.

Comment: @Roland I might have been overly simplistic in trying to create a reproducible example. Edited above

Comment: I've seen that. It doesn't change my comment. You should just name the list elements when you create the list. Otherwise, there is no good solution and you need to change what you are doing prior to this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you do

```
funclist <- list(a,b)
```

The parameters `a` and `b` are evaluated and the functions they point to are returned. There is no way to get back to the original names. (The `substitute()` "trick" works on parameters passed to functions as promises. It will not work on evaluated called without additional escaping.)

If you want to retain names, it's best to use a named list. You can do

```
funclist <- list(a=a,a=b)
```

or

```
funclist <- setNames(list(a,b), c("a","b"))
```

or even use `mget()` here

```
funclist <- mget(c("a","b"))
```

All these methods will returned a named list and you can use

```
names(funclist)
# [1] "a" "b"
```

to get the names

Comment: Then it would help if your reproducible example were more aligned with what you were actually doing. After you store an object in list, the name of that original object is not retained. If i do `a<-1; x<-list(a)`; There's no way to get back to `"a"` from `x`. All the parameters in the list are evaluated.

Comment: @Gregor, my mistake. Edited above

Comment: Replying to your edited answer: Fair enough, I did not realize that the function name was being dropped like that. Appreciate the clarification + suggestions.