# Obtain name of functions from list

Tags: r

Is there any way to obtain the names of functions from a list? For example is possible to do something like this?

```
sqrt <- function(x){
 squared <- (x*x)
}

divide <- function(x){
 half <- (x/2)
}

funclist <- list(sqrt, divide)

for(i in seq_along(funclist)){
printnameoffunction(funclist[[i]])
}
```

Comment: ...any way other than creating a named list in the first place, which is sort of the obvious thing to do?

Comment: Try `funclist  <- ls.str(mode = "function") ; funclist[1:length(funclist)]` maybe in order to get the functions names from the global environment. Other than that, (as previously mentioned), your list doesn't contain the functions names so nothing to extract.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741304/loop-over-list-of-functions-and-return-function-name-as-character